# Unexpected Realm property throws incorrect thread exception in correct thread with weird stacktrace

Tags: swift, realm

In my swift application i'm having this kind of pseudocode

1. Start a thread
2. Create an instance of Realm
3. Retrieve an object called User with property name
4. Used the name to create a NSMutableAttributedString
5. Fill up the rest of NSMutableAttributedString such as NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, and NSFontAttributeName
6. Incorrect thread exception is thrown

The stack trace is such as below

```
    Fatal Exception: RLMException
0   CoreFoundation                 0x1839fbd38 __exceptionPreprocess
1   libobjc.A.dylib                0x182f10528 objc_exception_throw
2   Realm                          0x1033e574c -[RLMRealm verifyThread] (RLMRealm.mm:156)
3   Realm                          0x103363d50 ___ZN12_GLOBAL__N_115makeBoxedGetterIN5realm10StringDataEEEP11objc_objectm_block_invoke (RLMAccessor.mm:51)
4   Foundation                     0x1842e9f70 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:]
5   Realm                          0x10337be98 -[RLMObjectBase valueForKey:] (RLMObjectBase.mm:178)
6   Realm                          0x10337d138 -[RLMObjectBase hash] (RLMObjectBase.mm:305)
7   UIFoundation                   0x18def3ab8 attributeDictionaryHash
8   Foundation                     0x1842ebedc hashProbe
9   Foundation                     0x1842f147c -[NSConcreteHashTable rehashAround:]
10  Foundation                     0x1842ec080 hashProbe
11  Foundation                     0x1842ed51c -[NSConcreteHashTable addObject:]
12  UIFoundation                   0x18def4628 -[NSAttributeDictionary newWithKey:object:]
13  Foundation                     0x1843082b4 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:]
14  Gate                         0x1004ef264 specialized MessageGenerator.replace(receivedMention : String, mentions : [String : User], senderID : String, meID : String, font : UIFont, availableWidth : CGFloat, outputAsText : Bool) -> NSAttributedString? (MessageGenerator.swift:147)
15  Gate                         0x1004ef7c8 specialized MessageGenerator.replaceMentionsForChats(originalString : String, mentions : [String : User], senderID : String, meID : String, font : UIFont, availableWidth : CGFloat, outputAsText : Bool) -> NSAttributedString (MessageGenerator.swift:176)
16  Gate                         0x1004f05c8 specialized MessageGenerator.getMentionReadyMessage(communicator : Communicator, conversationId : String, receivedString : String, mentions : [Mention], sentByMe : Bool, senderID : String, maxWidthForMention : CGFloat, font : UIFont?, outputAsText : Bool) -> NSAttributedString (MessageGenerator.swift:89)
17  Gate                         0x1004f0810 specialized MessageGenerator.prepareForMentionReadyMessage(communicator : Communicator, conversation : ConversationItem, message : Message, payload : TextPayload, maxWidthForMention : CGFloat, font : UIFont?, outputAsText : Bool) -> NSAttributedString? (MessageGenerator.swift:60)
18  Gate                         0x100508174 specialized WatchMessageVisitor.extractTextPayload(payload : TextPayload, input : String) -> NSAttributedString (WatchMessageVisitor.swift:62)
19  Gate                         0x1005082c8 specialized WatchMessageVisitor.visit(payload : TextPayload) -> () (WatchMessageVisitor.swift:41)
20  Gate                         0x1003ecea8 protocol witness for PayloadVisitor.visit(payload : TextPayload) -> () in conformance MessageTextInterpreter (MessageTextInterpreter.swift)
21  Codebase                       0x101d27b2c TextPayloadCodebasePayloadProtocol (Payload.swift:93)
22  Gate                         0x1003edd38 specialized MessageTextInterpreter.init(communicator : Communicator, conversation : ConversationItem, message : Message?, maxWidthForMention : CGFloat, fontForMention : UIFont?) -> MessageTextInterpreter (MessageTextInterpreter.swift:46)
23  Gate                         0x1003780b8 WatchWrapperserialise[[String : Any]]LazyArray (Bootstrap.swift)
24  Gate                         0x100378620 WatchWrapperserialise[[String : Any]]LazyArray (Bootstrap.swift:71)
25  Gate                         0x100377364 WatchWrapperCodebaseWatchSerializerGateWatchSerializerserialise[[String : Any]]LazyArray (Bootstrap.swift)
26  Codebase                       0x101d75740 WatchManagerModule.(updateWatchData() -> ()).(closure #1) (WatchManagerModule.swift:57)
27  Codebase                       0x101d78e70 partial apply for thunk (WatchManagerModule.swift)
28  RxSwift                        0x105331d5c ObservableTypesubscribeDisposable(A.E) -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) -> ()?onError() -> ()?onCompleted (ObservableType+Extensions.swift:104)
29  RxSwift                        0x105331a80 ObservableTypesubscribeDisposable(A.E) -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) -> ()?onError() -> ()?onCompleted (ObservableType+Extensions.swift)
30  RxSwift                        0x105331bec ObservableTypesubscribeDisposable(A.E) -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) -> ()?onError() -> ()?onCompleted (ObservableType+Extensions.swift)
31  RxSwift                        0x1052dc2b8 AnonymousObserver.onCore(Event<A>) -> () (AnonymousObserver.swift:24)
32  RxSwift                        0x1053345c0 ObserverBase.on(Event<A>) -> () (ObserverBase.swift:21)
33  RxSwift                        0x10533487c ObserverBase<A>RxSwiftObserverTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (ObserverBase.swift)
34  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
35  RxSwift                        0x10530bcb0 AnonymousObservableSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (Create.swift:50)
36  RxSwift                        0x10530be40 AnonymousObservableSink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (Create.swift)
37  RxSwift                        0x105334c08 partial apply (ObserverType.swift)
38  RxSwift                        0x1052dc498 AnyObserver.on(Event<A>) -> () (AnyObserver.swift:39)
39  RxSwift                        0x1052dc508 AnyObserver<A>RxSwiftObserverTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (AnyObserver.swift)
40  RxSwift                        0x105334a04 ObserverType.onNext(A.E) -> () (ObserverType.swift:28)
41  Codebase                       0x101d24ba4 static Observable.(fromCallable(action : () throws -> A?) -> Observable<A>).(closure #1)LazyArray
42  RxSwift                        0x10530bf5c AnonymousObservable.run<A where ...> (A1, cancel : Cancelable) -> (sink : Disposable, subscription : Disposable) (Create.swift:60)
43  RxSwift                        0x10533f95c Producer.subscribe<A where ...> (A1) -> Disposable (Producer.swift:19)
44  RxSwift                        0x105331958 ObservableTypesubscribeDisposable(A.E) -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) -> ()?onError() -> ()?onCompleted (ObservableType+Extensions.swift:124)
45  Codebase                       0x101d7568c WatchManagerModule.updateWatchData() -> () (WatchManagerModule.swift:58)
46  Codebase                       0x101d7614c WatchSyncCandidate.onComplete() -> () (WatchManagerModule.swift:170)
47  Codebase                       0x101d50354 SyncRunner.run(communicator : Communicator, entities : [SyncHandler]) -> Observable<()>Communicator (SyncRunner.swift:86)
48  Codebase                       0x101d4f1f8 SyncRunner.run(communicator : Communicator, entities : [SyncHandler]) -> Observable<()>Communicator (SyncRunner.swift)
49  RxSwift                        0x10531b15c ObservableTypedoObservable<A.E>(A.E) throws -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) throws -> ()?onError() throws -> ()?onCompleted() -> ()?onSubscribe (Do.swift:32)
50  RxSwift                        0x10531b3d0 ObservableTypedoObservable<A.E>(A.E) throws -> ()?onNext first-element-marker (Error) throws -> ()?onError() throws -> ()?onCompleted() -> ()?onSubscribe (Do.swift)
51  RxSwift                        0x10531b514 DoSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (Do.swift:51)
52  RxSwift                        0x10531b89c DoSink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (Do.swift)
53  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
54  RxSwift                        0x105367e40 SwitchIfEmptySinkIter.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (SwitchIfEmpty.swift:96)
55  RxSwift                        0x10536802c SwitchIfEmptySinkIter<A>RxSwiftObserverType (SwitchIfEmpty.swift)
56  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
57  RxSwift                        0x10530bc48 AnonymousObservableSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (Create.swift:53)
58  RxSwift                        0x10530be40 AnonymousObservableSink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (Create.swift)
59  RxSwift                        0x105334c08 partial apply (ObserverType.swift)
60  RxSwift                        0x1052dc498 AnyObserver.on(Event<A>) -> () (AnyObserver.swift:39)
61  RxSwift                        0x1052dc508 AnyObserver<A>RxSwiftObserverTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (AnyObserver.swift)
62  RxSwift                        0x105334a90 ObserverType.onCompleted() -> () (ObserverType.swift:33)
63  Codebase                       0x101d24f88 specialized static Observable.(execute(action : () throws -> ()) -> Observable<A>).(closure #1) (Observable+Ext.swift:36)
64  RxSwift                        0x10530bf5c AnonymousObservable.run<A where ...> (A1, cancel : Cancelable) -> (sink : Disposable, subscription : Disposable) (Create.swift:60)
65  RxSwift                        0x10533f95c Producer.subscribe<A where ...> (A1) -> Disposable (Producer.swift:19)
66  RxSwift                        0x105367a78 SwitchIfEmptySink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (SwitchIfEmpty.swift:76)
67  RxSwift                        0x105367cec SwitchIfEmptySink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (SwitchIfEmpty.swift)
68  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
69  RxSwift                        0x10532aa08 MergeSink.on(Event<A>) -> () (Merge.swift:529)
70  RxSwift                        0x10532b86c MergeSink<A, B, C>RxSwiftObserverType (Merge.swift)
71  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
72  RxSwift                        0x10532b6e4 MergeSinkIter.on(Event<B.E>) -> () (Merge.swift:529)
73  RxSwift                        0x10532b74c MergeSinkIter<A, B, C>RxSwiftObserverType (Merge.swift)
74  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
75  RxSwift                        0x105313678 DefaultIfEmptySink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (DefaultIfEmpty.swift:46)
76  RxSwift                        0x1053138f0 DefaultIfEmptySink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (DefaultIfEmpty.swift)
77  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
78  RxSwift                        0x10532aa08 MergeSink.on(Event<A>) -> () (Merge.swift:529)
79  RxSwift                        0x10532b86c MergeSink<A, B, C>RxSwiftObserverType (Merge.swift)
80  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
81  RxSwift                        0x10532b6e4 MergeSinkIter.on(Event<B.E>) -> () (Merge.swift:529)
82  RxSwift                        0x10532b74c MergeSinkIter<A, B, C>RxSwiftObserverType (Merge.swift)
83  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
84  RxSwift                        0x105363ac4 SubscribeOnSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (SubscribeOn.swift:44)
85  RxSwift                        0x105364530 SubscribeOnSink<A, B>RxSwiftObserverType (SubscribeOn.swift)
86  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
87  RxSwift                        0x1053140e0 DeferredSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (Deferred.swift:47)
88  RxSwift                        0x1053143ec DeferredSink<A, B>RxSwiftObserverType (Deferred.swift)
89  RxSwift                        0x10535e60c Sink.forwardOn(Event<A.E>) -> () (Sink.swift:36)
90  RxSwift                        0x10530bc48 AnonymousObservableSink.on(Event<A.E>) -> () (Create.swift:53)
91  RxSwift                        0x10530be40 AnonymousObservableSink<A>RxSwiftObserverType (Create.swift)
92  RxSwift                        0x105334c08 partial apply (ObserverType.swift)
93  RxSwift                        0x1052dc498 AnyObserver.on(Event<A>) -> () (AnyObserver.swift:39)
94  RxSwift                        0x1052dc508 AnyObserver<A>RxSwiftObserverTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (AnyObserver.swift)
95  RxSwift                        0x105334a90 ObserverType.onCompleted() -> () (ObserverType.swift:33)
96  Codebase                       0x101d24f88 specialized static Observable.(execute(action : () throws -> ()) -> Observable<A>).(closure #1) (Observable+Ext.swift:36)
97  RxSwift                        0x10530bf5c AnonymousObservable.run<A where ...> (A1, cancel : Cancelable) -> (sink : Disposable, subscription : Disposable) (Create.swift:60)
98  RxSwift                        0x10533f95c Producer.subscribe<A where ...> (A1) -> Disposable (Producer.swift:19)
99  RxSwift                        0x1053313e4 Observable<A>RxSwiftObservableTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (Observable.swift)
100 RxSwift                        0x105313fb4 DeferredSink.run() -> Disposable (Deferred.swift:37)
101 RxSwift                        0x1053144c8 Deferred.run<A where ...> (A1, cancel : Cancelable) -> (sink : Disposable, subscription : Disposable) (Deferred.swift:72)
102 RxSwift                        0x10533feb0 Producer.(subscribe<A where ...> (A1) -> Disposable).(closure #1) (Producer.swift:27)
103 RxSwift                        0x10530c67c specialized specialized CurrentThreadScheduler.schedule<A> (A, action : (A) -> Disposable) -> Disposable (CurrentThreadScheduler.swift:66)
104 RxSwift                        0x10533faa8 Producer.subscribe<A where ...> (A1) -> Disposable (Producer.swift:30)
105 RxSwift                        0x1053313e4 Observable<A>RxSwiftObservableTypeRxSwift<A>RxSwift (Observable.swift)
106 RxSwift                        0x105363f98 SubscribeOnSink.(run() -> Disposable).(closure #1) (SubscribeOn.swift:59)
107 RxSwift                        0x1053695fc thunk (Take.swift)
108 RxSwift                        0x105318ce8 specialized DispatchQueueConfiguration.(schedule<A> (A, action : (A) -> Disposable) -> Disposable).(closure #1) (DispatchQueueConfiguration.swift:34)
109 RxSwift                        0x1053191e8 partial apply for DispatchQueueConfiguration.(schedule<A> (A, action : (A) -> Disposable) -> Disposable).(closure #1) (DispatchQueueConfiguration.swift)
110 RxSwift                        0x10530b4a8 thunk (ConcurrentMainScheduler.swift)
111 libdispatch.dylib              0x183381088 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
112 libdispatch.dylib              0x183381048 _dispatch_client_callout
113 libdispatch.dylib              0x1833893d4 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp
114 libdispatch.dylib              0x183387d88 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke$VARIANT$mp
115 libdispatch.dylib              0x18338e1c8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
116 libdispatch.dylib              0x18338df10 _dispatch_worker_thread3
117 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183627130 _pthread_wqthread
118 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x183626c30 start_wqthread
```

which comes from code snippet such as below

```swift
let user = realm.object(ofType: User.self, forPrimaryKey: $0.identifier)
let name = "@\(user.nickname)"

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " " + name + " ")
let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: text.length)

text.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: #colorLiteral(red:0.3058823529, green:0.6156862745, blue:0.9254901961, alpha:1), range: range)
text.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: #colorLiteral(red:1, green:1, blue:1, alpha:1), range: range)
text.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: font, range: range)
```

What makes me wonder is why the Realm code is being executed within NSMutableAttributedString internal codes, where as what is being used is the name which a String.

Secondly all the codes is actually executed within same thread, not main thread though.

In the app we do have one or two threads withholding object retrieved from their own Realm thread instances.

This crash is reported through Crashlytic, and i've been unable to reproduce the scenario, however the crash is still happening.

Hopefully someone can shed a light on what is actually going on.

Comment: Can you share a more complete crash log so we can better understand the context in which the crash is occurring? The only thing that can be inferred from what you've shared so far is that somehow an instance of an `Object` subclass has ended up as the key in an attributed string's attribute dictionary. That clearly doesn't happen due to the code snippet you've shared.

Comment: Exactly that is why i don't understand it either, but it happened. Let me put more crash log

Comment: @yunarta RxSwift calls `subscribe` on the thread scheduler specified by` observeOn`. You may unconsciously use multiple threads. I do not know the details from your shared code, but passing a `User` object seems bad practice, you should pass just `name` instead.

Comment: We even tested preventing the issue by firstly assigned the name first with `let user = String(user.nickname)` and then using it into the NSMutableAttributedString, but the problem is still there.

What amazes me is that what cause the Realm object becoming the key of NSMutableAttributedString. 

We will continue to monitor and let you know if we found more interesting stuff.